# Unable to download Appium

Tags: download, appium

I am trying to download Appium, but I'm seeing this screen:

[image]

On clicking any of the links, I'm not getting desired exe file. I searched for the same over site, but I've found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The link which ends with **...beta.2.exe** is the one that you have to use. It's the download link for Appium Desktop windows version.

If you are looking for a more detailed guide, then please check out this link for a step by step tutorial - [Download and Install Appium Desktop](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop/)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually, it's an updated version that made me confuse.

Answer (score 0):

@BhoomikaGulati , hi .

Just aside note-  personally for me out of the box  [Appium Studio for Intellij](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TD/Appium+Studio+for+Intellij) 
 worked like a charm.

Speaking shortly, its  version of open-source Appium, that improves on Appium testing. It is a free community tool with  support that comes in the form of the forum and online self-training sessions.
Take a look in this [step-by-step](https://www.softwaretestingnews.co.uk/take-appium-testing-to-the-next-level-with-appium-studio/) manual,

regards, Eugene

Answer (score 0):

You can install appium using Node.js. If you have node.js or after download and install node.js you can install appium as mentioned below. Open command-line and use this command for specific version.

```
npm install -g appium@1.7.1
```

or install latest version as

```
npm install -g appium
```

Hope it will help.